# Extra keys in web.config of web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, web

```
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Are these keys redundant for web api project if we use angular for client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove those keys from the web config.

In our application, we have used our custom keys in app settings and some other configurations

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders />
</httpProtocol>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

We have used  [Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/) at API side to enable cross-orgin.

Hope it helps

Comment: what? how is this considered the answer.If you are not using the key then you don't need it. I don't see how adding all this addition `system.web` helps in giving someone understand. its like asking about apples and bring oranges into the conversation. Maybe modify your answer answer and remove parts which ain't applicable - which leads to the answer to the original question. If its not applicable then remove ;-)